# How to mock a Class Object? And mock a non exist field in a Class?

Tags: java, android, mockito, powermockito

I know mocking a class is not a good idea. But I meet the problem.  Our real code will run on android devices which has a system class A. One device's Class A has special field B, but other does not exist. Though A is system class, it's be modified by device manufacture.

So I should mock a A class Object having B field.

```
Class A { static Object B}
```

How I mock a A Class Object? Or how to create a field in the system class A ?  I run the code on pc and using mockito and powermockito.

Comment: You don't use object mocks on production apps.  That's intended for unit testing only.  So it's not clear to me what you're really trying to accomplish.

Comment: What difference would it make for your test if that class has a field B or not? (if your test today expects that field, then your test is not compiling - unles you are checking that field through reflection...)

Comment: @Doug Stevenson Yes, I just test code blocks with it.  My problem is what the title describes. Mock a A Class Object and mock to create a field that does not exist in a class. Is it possible?